# C# Tasks in a loop never ends

Tags: c#, multithreading

Consider this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    int i1 = i;
    Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine(i1));
}
```

I write a loop from 0 to 1000000 when running above code,loop never completes.
Why this loop never completes?

Comment: how long did you wait?

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly should complete if and then out of programm

Comment: @dtb no work on my machin

Comment: So what happens on your machine? Does it print all 1000000 numbers and then hang? Just a few numbers? How do you determine that it hangs? Can you rule out that another part of your code is responsible for the behavior you see?

Comment: no when i write             Console.ReadLine();
 all thing is ok but when without Console.ReadLine(); brake the loop and exit from application

Comment: @ShahroozJefriㇱ as I wrote in my answer, that's because Task.Run does run the task asynchronously to the thread your console is running in. If you don't wait for the tasks to complete, your console will simple exit the thread.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thats because you never wait for your task to complete. I expect you run this within a console application. The console thread will actually exit before your loop completes because `Task.Run` runs the task asynchronously to the thread of your console application.

Either you wait for the task to complete

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            int i1 = i;
            Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine(i1)).Wait();
        }
```

Or you keep your console window open

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            int i1 = i;
            Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine(i1));
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Or you wait for all tasks to complete by adding them to a list and use `Task.WaitAll`

```
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            int i1 = i;
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine(i1)));
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 3):

`Task` is running in [background thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h339syd0.aspx). When the main thread stops all tasks are terminated. If you add `Task.WaitAll` after your code, it will work.

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    int i1 = i;
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine(i1)));
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works perfectly on my OS X with Mono:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            int i1 = i;
            Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine(i1));
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```